# How to properly run devtools::revdep_check()?

Tags: r, devtools

How should I properly run `devtools::revdep_check()` against dependencies of my package? When I run it like `check()` it builds all the packages that are currently instilled on my PC and this is not needed and lasts forever. Unfortunately the documentation is very limited and lacks examples.

Comment: What else would you expect? The docs seem to be quite clear, that it will reinstall packages each time in a temporary library which can be avoided by setting `options(devtools.revdep.libpath)` to a directory on your machine.

Comment: @ThomasK but all of the packages I have installed? What for?! Moreover, I once was able to suppress this behavior, but can't recall how...